# Android: Export part of my SQLlite table to a file and upload it to the Database of the same app on a differnet phone

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to figure out how to export a specific part of my Database to a file and then send the file to a friend to open it on his phone and to automatically insert the values from that file into his Database in the same application.

So the idea is to be able to share a specific part of my Database. That way I will be able to have the option to send the file through messaging, e-mailing, etc.... . That will also give me the opportutnity to backup the user data upon user request. I have no idea what I need and how can I do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like:

**Step1**:
Load the data you want to share.

**Step2**:
Convert it to SQL queries.

**Step3**:
Send it to other device using web service.

**Step4**:
Run the SQL queries on other device.

Comment: So would that be considered sending a file or simply using web service? I would like to have an actual file, hence I will be able to allow the option to backup/export your table values to a file on your sd card and import them back, say if you want to format your phone... What would be a possible solution for such functionality? Thanks